# Quarkus 1.13.7 + OptaPlanner 8.7.0 error - Illegal char in quarkus-core-deployment-1.13.7.Final.jar

Tags: java, maven, drools, optaplanner

I have updated OptaPlanner 8.1.0 to 8.7.0 and I have this error (I'm on Windows). I have deleted all my cache and reinstall all the packages but nothing change, same error. Same when I deleted all the files manually.

```shell
 ERROR [io.qua.ver.htt.run.QuarkusErrorHandler] (executor-thread-1) HTTP
     Request to /affectationPlanning?idResolution=3 failed, error id: e2bf302c-ce1c-4914-abf2-a5cca
    6bd4eb0-1: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illeg
    al char <:> at index 4: file:///C:/Users/lolo/.m2/repository/io/quarkus/quarkus-core-deployment
    /1.13.7.Final/quarkus-core-deployment-1.13.7.Final.jar
```

I use Quarkus 1.13.7.Final,everything is working fine with OptaPlanner 8.1.0, there the pom.xml :

if someone has already solved this problem or has a lead to help me, thanks in advance :-)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.acme</groupId>
  <artifactId>myapp-solver</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <properties>
    <compiler-plugin.version>3.8.1</compiler-plugin.version>
    <maven.compiler.release>11</maven.compiler.release>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <surefire-plugin.version>3.0.0-M5</surefire-plugin.version>
    <version.io.quarkus>1.13.7.Final</version.io.quarkus>
    <version.org.optaplanner>8.7.0.Final</version.org.optaplanner>
  </properties>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-bom</artifactId>
        <version>${version.io.quarkus}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.optaplanner</groupId>
        <artifactId>optaplanner-bom</artifactId>
        <version>${version.org.optaplanner}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-jdbc-mysql</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-rest-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-jackson</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-orm-panache</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-jdbc-h2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-orm-rest-data-panache</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.optaplanner</groupId>
      <artifactId>optaplanner-quarkus</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.optaplanner</groupId>
      <artifactId>optaplanner-quarkus-jackson</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-test-h2</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
      <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.optaplanner</groupId>
      <artifactId>optaplanner-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-webjars-locator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
      <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
      <version>4.5.3</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
      <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
      <version>3.5.1</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
      <artifactId>font-awesome</artifactId>
      <version>5.15.1</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
      <artifactId>momentjs</artifactId>
      <version>2.24.0</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${compiler-plugin.version}</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${version.io.quarkus}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>build</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <systemPropertyVariables>
            <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
          </systemPropertyVariables>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>native</id>
      <activation>
        <property>
          <name>native</name>
        </property>
      </activation>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <goals>
                  <goal>integration-test</goal>
                  <goal>verify</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <native.image.path>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-runner</native.image.path>
                  </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
      <properties>
        <quarkus.profile>native</quarkus.profile>
        <quarkus.package.type>native</quarkus.package.type>
      </properties>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are aware of the issue and we have a fix for OptaPlanner 8.8.0.Final, which will hopefully be released soon. In the meantime, as a workaround, you may want to switch to some other operating system than Windows - this issue is exclusive to Windows.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, indeed I forgot an important information: I am on Windows!